# How do i update sql value with sum comparison

Tags: sql-update

I am trying to update a value to show the picked status of an order based on the picked status against the order qty. The data is in the same table but i cannot figure out the correct syntax. I tried:
Update Orders set Status = 'FULL' where Sum(Qty_Order) = sum(Qty_Picked)
How can i apply this logic using an aggregate query?
Thanks in advance for any help/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach uses an update join:

```sql
UPDATE Orders o1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING SUM(Qty_Order) = SUM(Qty_Picked)
) o2
    ON o2.id = o1.id
SET
    Status = 'FULL';
```

This assumes that your `Orders` table has a column `id` which uniquely identifies each order.